# Issues while validating the two JSON payloads in MUNIT 2.0

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, munit

I have a service which is returning the below json payload:

```
{

  "location-details": {

    "fromPostalCode": "1508XB",

    "fromGeoCoordinates": "116532,496398",

    "toPostalCode": "1511MA",

    "toGeoCoordinates": "120427,493380"

  },

  "commute-distance": "5817.799",

  "commute-time": "370.0152"

}
```

I have created a MUNIT test suite for the same where i am using the assert that utility to assert the payload. Snippet given below:

```
<munit:validation >
<munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert That Status Code is 200" doc:id="1c2e536b-513e-4b76-958b-2ea864a64805" expression="#[attributes.statusCode]" is="#[MunitTools::equalTo(200)]" message="The HTTP Status code is not correct!" />
<munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert That - Payload is Expected" doc:id="f4b811fa-ff11-4746-93cc-f87576504808" expression="#[payload]" is="#[MunitTools::getResourceAsString('SuccessResponse.json')]" message="The response payload is not correct!"/>
</munit:validation>
```

But this is throwing an below error and its not working:

```
...38 more

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException: Unable to convert '{
  "location-details": {
    "fromPostalCode": "1508XB",
    "fromGeoCoordinates": "116532,496398",
    "toPostalCode": "1511MA",
    "toGeoCoordinates": "120427,493380"
  },
  "commute-distance": "5817.799",
  "commute-time": "370.0152"

}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'Matcher', while writing Java at org.mule.munit.tools.util.GetResourceFunctions.getResourceAsString.

               at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguage.doEvaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguage.scala:139)
               at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguage.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguage.scala:236)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the matcher component in your expression, please change it as below and try again:

```html
<munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert Payload is Correct" doc:id="5b45470f-05e8-406e-9d44-877ff1506220" expression='#[output application/json ---  write(payload, "application/json")]' is="#[output application/json --- MunitTools::equalTo(MunitTools::getResourceAsString('json\SuccessResponse.json'))]" message="The message is not correct"/>
```

This will work for sure !!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `readUrl` instead of `MunitTools::getResourceAsString` to compare two JSON objects in **MUNIT 2.1**

```
<munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert That - JSON compare" doc:id="2fab5bf0-a710-4619-a7a9-262a867e0ad9" expression="#[payload]" is="#[MunitTools::equalTo(readUrl('classpath://sample_data/test_payload.json', 'application/json'))]" message="payload is not correct" />
```

Comment: currently in 2022 this works! Thanks